# How to optimize android code

Tags: java, android, coding-style, standards

```
public String getBrotherHood() throws Exception{        
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    get = new HttpGet(uri);
    res = client.execute(get);
    sl = res.getStatusLine();
    sCode = sl.getStatusCode();
    if(sCode==200)
    {
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.getEntity().getContent()));
            readBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while((nl = reader.readLine())!=null){
                readBuffer.append(nl);
            }
            reader.close();
        }finally{
            if(reader !=null)
            {
                try{
                    reader.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return readBuffer.toString();       
  }
}
```

I have this code, is this the proper way of writing it, or should i need to follow any coding pattern or standards ??

Please give me some suggestions coz im not to Android Coding.

**Update:**

```
public class JSONData {

public ArrayList<String> getBrotherHoodJSON() throws JSONException,IOException,Exception{
    ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jA = new JSONArray(getBrotherHood());

    for(int i=0; i<jA.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jO = jA.getJSONObject(i);
        String n = jO.getString("name");
        item.add(n);
        Log.i("JsonData:",jO.getString("name"));
    }

    return item;
}   

public String getBrotherHood() throws Exception{    
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data= null;
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI uri = new URI("http://fahidmohammad.in/demo/Android/api.php?user=fah");
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
    get.setURI(uri);
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(get);
    StatusLine sl = res.getStatusLine();
    int sCode = sl.getStatusCode();
    if(sCode==200)
    {
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String nl;
            while((nl = in.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            Log.i("Raw Data:",data);
            return data;
        }finally{
            if(in !=null)
            {
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;        
}
```

Here is the updated version the same code.
Taken care of all the mentioned issues.

And also its working like a charm, but don't know the stability of it.

Comment: Look at this for some conventions tips, http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: don't catch all exception `Exception e`. Catch only that `Exceptions` that method can throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have declared all variables outside your method even though they seem to be used only within this method. That makes no sense. It prevents several objects from being garbage collected. You better move the declaration into the method.

And the declaration `throws Exception` doesn't make much sense either. You are better of if you either declare a specific exception that could likely occur or if you convert all unlikely exceptions into `RuntimeException` so you don't need to declare them.

Comment: Wow that's a nice piece of information :) Sure ill follow what you have mentioned. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a default code formatter is available eclipse. after wrote your code just type **"Control + Shift + F"**. Your android code will formatting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

one more important point regrading readBuffer varible

At the last of the function you are returning readBuffer.toString() and you initialized this only when status in 200.  But if status in not 200 then it would be null (assuming as declaration is not visible ) so null.toString() will thought exception.